# Laravel, how to change/rearrange datatable buttons and records entries?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dom, datatable

My goal is to arrange button and other functionalities as show in the picture below:

[image]

How to,

- make extra button and place at top left
- put record entries and search bar side by side and place it at top right
- excel and pdf at bottom left
- pagination at bottom right

So far what I did was using dom, but the outcome is the record entries still at top left and no extra buttons at the top left.

```
dom: "lfrtpB",
pageLength: 10,
lengthMenu: [ 5, 10, 30, 50 ],
buttons: [
   {
       extend: 'pdf',
       exportOptions: {
           columns: [0,1,2,3]
       }
   },
   {
       extend: 'csv',
       exportOptions: {
           columns: [0,1,2,3]
       }
   },
   {
       extend: 'excel',
   }
],
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet and add it to your question? That would allow us to play around with your code and solve your problem. Don't worry about how the data is to be received, let's mock the data with some hard-coded stuff., because the issue is more related to the UI.